# Multiple cameras on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, camera

I am very new here, and I really want to know if it is possible to run 4 camera module to make a video at the same time, even if I use the multiple camera module*? I want to make a 360 degree video using a Raspberry Pi by implementing 4 camera module pi simultaneously

*camera module = http://www.arducam.com/multi-camera-adapter-module-raspberry-pi/

Comment: What multiple camera module? Are you referring to the Pi camera or a USB camera? Why do you need 4 cameras to make a video?

Comment: I think you're best off asking the Arducam folks that, wael.

Comment: Also note that this module is compatible with RPi 1 and 2, according to the product page. Not sure if you can use it with RPi 3.

Comment: A couple of things I noticed from the link you provided: 1)  "Please note that Raspberry Pi multi camera adapter board is nascent product that may have some stability issues and limitations because of the cable’s signal integrity and RPi’s closed source video core libraries, so use it on your own risk." This would lead me to believe that this is not ready for serious use and may never be. 2) They do not include a video showing it working?

Comment: 3) nor do they include any mention of what performance you can expect, but given that you are trying to quadruple the workload, I would expect the frame rate to suffer correspondingly. You may be better off searching for raspberry pi 360 degree cam. I have seen a few options here: 1) a lens type attachment and an array of Pi zero's with multiple cameras, There are likely other options as well.

Comment: For the record the RPi Compute Module does support __two__ RPi cameras simultaneously on two separate connectors.

Answer (score 4):

That camera adapter is a multiplexer.

What it means, is that you use software to select which camera you want to get video from and then record it.

It is unclear if the camera has to initialise after you selected it.. or if it is constantly streaming video and all you are doing is "switching channels"

The best application for this is 3D photography. So basically static objects that do not move.

What you are trying to do with 360video will not work. After stitching you will get black holes all over the place and probably induce vomiting.

You may get better results using USB WebCams that encode h264 on the webcam and store the stream on the Pi, download the data to a Xenon 3.8Ghz and stitch it...

Ahhh.. were you thinking you could stream and stitch on the Pi? "No way, José"

Answer (score 1):

[UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) support *videorooms*. You can stream to a videoroom from **any** Raspberry Pi 2 or 3. Where is this videoroom? On the Raspberry Pi itself! if you want. In facts, UV4L comes with a [ready-to-use OS image](http://www.linux-projects.org/rpi-videoconference-demo-os/) with an MCU that can host the videoroom itself. UV4L supports the following input real or virtual devices: official camera modules, USB webcams, IP Cam streams, etc..(each participant can also stream audio, if you are interested in this). A participant can also be a browser (no plug-in is required). And audio/video can optionally be two-way.

In substance, you have plenty of options here: you can have 4 live streams from your 4 Rpi's or cameras (e.g. 4 IP cams or 2 Dual CM) and as "producers" for the video stream, and one browser or Rpi as "consumer". In the PC browser you can do plenty of things to process the incoming videos. Being everything web-based the OS should be easy to tweak. Finally, there is also a [RESTful API](http://www.linux-projects.org/documentation/rest-api/) if you want to write native applications or to access the Rpi H264 encoder for high-res full-fps streams.